# Pass Javascript Array in Array using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, tinymce

I get my fields like array with javascript. Every array field is array with proporties.

Example.

```
arr[0]
{
  'id':'1',
  'title':'testtitle',
  'value': 'test value'
}
arr[1]
{
  'id':'2',
  'title':'testtitle',
  'value': 'test value'
}
arr[2]
{
  'id':'3',
  'title':'testtitle',
  'value': 'test value'
}
```

I use `JSON.stringify(arr);` to send array to php and to read this array.
My problem is, Value option is text form textarea. When I use simple text , I have no problem. But I need to use `TinyMCE` editor. When I paste some text where have html like this:

```
style="font-size:12px;" and other ...
```

Array crashed. I have no idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encode the contents of that textarea with something like Base64 first, before sending it. In PHP you can then decode and use it again.

JS ([`btoa()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.btoa)):

```
arr.value = window.btoa( textareaContent );
```

PHP ([`base64_decode()`](https://www.php.net/base64_decode) ):

```
$value = base64_decode( encodedString );
```

Comment: Thank You for advise :) You save my day ! I make decode whit this (jQuery plugin base64) becose whit btoa() i have problems. Now all Work thanks alot :)

Comment: And One mor Thing. In php Whit base64_decode() things is broken. I use this function like : $result = base64_decode(str_replace(" ","+",$STING_TO_DECODE); and all work fine . Hope i help someone :)